# ruby gem inclusion still requires explicit dependencies in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I have a Gem project that has the following in the **mygem.gemspec** file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|

  s.add_dependency 'some_other_gem'

end
```

Everything builds and publishes just fine for the Gem.

In my Rails projects that use it, I have the following in my **Gemfile**:

```
source 'http://abc123@gem.fury.io/my_user/' do
  gem 'mygem', '1.12'
end
```

When I run my projects, I need to explicitly add  the following in the **Gemfile** or else I wind up with dependency errors:

```
'some_other_gem', '3.14'

source 'http://abc123@gem.fury.io/my_user/' do
  gem 'mygem', '1.12'
end
```

Project's Rails version is 5.0.6 running on Ruby 2.3.1.

Is there more necessary than just `s.add_dependency` in my **mygem.gemspec** file?

Comment: I have never seen the `"=3.14"` syntax before. I think `"3.14"` (i.e. without the equals sign) is preferred. Also: when you say "dependency errors", could you be more specific? Can you post the error?

Comment: I was trying to create a project to simulate the issue but cannot reproduce it.  It is only happening in one of my projects so I'll need to dig a little more to get the errors (it's not an easy app to run locally).  I'll get it here as soon as I can.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it at all now.  It must have just been a fluke.  :confused:

Comment: Are you sure that version `1.12` of `mygem` published in gem.fury does depend on `my_other_gem`? Or was that dependency added on a later version?